# htop shows only the processes of the user that's running it?

Tags: linux, permissions, process, proc

On my old Debian Wheezy I see as a normal user without *sudo* all processes from all user in `htop`. On my new Debian Wheezy I only see my own processes.

- **Old system kernel**: 3.2.0-4
- **New system kernel**: 3.14.32

The difference that I noticed is that on the old system `/proc/1/` has `r-xr-xr-x` permissions and on the new one only `r-x------`.

The line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
proc            /proc         proc   defaults  0      0
```

`mount` returns the following:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

When I add `hidepid=0` and reboot:`hidepid=0`.

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options>           <dump> <pass>
proc            /proc         proc   defaults,hidepid=0  0      0
```

`mount` still returns the same as without:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

What should I do to see all processes as a normal user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.
The kernel was compiled with *grsecurity*, which hides processes from other users.
With default kernel everything works fine.

Comment: Huh, is grsec really the default on Debian now?

Comment: No, it is not. But my colleague, who created the installation, use grsec as default and forgot to tell me about it.

Answer (score 2):

`hidepid` is a mount option for procfs that hides processes from other users. There are three settings:

1. `hidepid=0`: Anyone can read the world-readable files in `/proc/PID`
2. `hidepid=1`: Users can only access the `/proc/PID` directories and files that belong to their user.
3. `hidepid=2`: The same as `hidepid=1`, but the processes of other users will not even be visible in `/proc/PID`

To see the mount options that `/proc` was mounted with you can run `mount | grep /proc`.

For more information, see the mount options section in the kernel documentation for the [proc filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), and the [nixCraft article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-hide-processes-from-other-users/) on the subject.

Comment: Adding `hidepid=0` made no difference for me.